# Hola, Necesito insertar datos en 2 tablas de forma simultanea

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Necesito insertar datos en 2 tablas de forma simultanea, con la condicion de que se hagan las 2 inserciones o ninguna. Por ejemplo tengo estos 2 modelos, User y Authentication, por ende cuando inserte un usuario se debe generar otra tabla con email y una pass. Estoy usando Sequelize y quisiera **realizarlo con include: [ ]**  Estoy trabajndo con una base de datos PostgreSQL

***Model User***

```
    import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
    import { sequelize } from '../database/database';
    import Authentication from './Authentication';

    const User = sequelize.define('users', {
        id:{
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        ci:{
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            unique: true
        },
        name:{
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            unique: true
        },
        lastname: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        status: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
        }
    },{
        timestamps: false
    });

    User.hasOne(Authentication);
    Authentication.belongsTo(User);

    export default User;
```

***Model Authentication***

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../database/database';

const Authentication = sequelize.define('authentications',{
    id:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    email:{
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        unique: true,
        validate:{
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    password:{
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    userid:{
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
},{
    timestamps: false
});

export default Authentication;
```

> ---
>
> Y como lo he tratado de hacer elo adjunto en la respuesta:

---

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar más datos de las tablas involucradas si es posible la definición de las mismas? Tengo una idea de como resolverlo, pero necesito el DDL de las tablas. Saldus!.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
 id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
 ci TEXT NOT NULL,
 name TEXT NOT NULL,
 lastname TEXT NOT NULL,
 status BOOBLEAN DEFAULT true
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authentications(
 id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
 email TEXT NOT NULL,
 password TEXT NOT NULL,
 userid TEXT REFERENCE users(id)
);`

Comment: @Blasito no es posible definirlas, pero tengo del DDL, Gracias!